# Using an External JS Library Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dropzone.js

I want to use the simple example dropzone js in an angular 2 project:
http://www.dropzonejs.com/examples/simple.html

Is there an easy way to use the js for simple drag and drop functionality? I tried adding installing using:

```
npm i dropzone --save
```

And referencing the script from node_modules in index.html, but it doesn't seem to work.

Plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Gk2xtoH1FhOe6hko6z8K?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, The easiest way to include an external library into an angular 2 project is as follows:

1)  include it in your HTML file as a script tag

```
<script src="js/your-library.js"></script>
```

2) To use the library you must add the following to one of your ts/js files:

```
declare var libraryVar: any;
```

or

```
var libraryVar
```

Where libraryVar is the name of a function from the library you're including, so for example, to include jQuery, you would use:

```
declare let $:any;
```